# Angular map-marker-clusterer component doesn't work

Tags: angular, google-maps, markerclusterer, angular13

I'm using the map as follow, but this doesn't works

```html
<google-map #googleMap width="100%" height="100%" (idle)="initClusterer($event)">
  <map-marker-clusterer *ngIf="googleMap?.googleMap">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let i of items">
      <ng-container *ngIf="i.categories | haveCategory: targetCategory">
        <map-marker #markerElem [position]="i.position"> </map-marker>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </map-marker-clusterer>
</google-map>
```

```js
import { MarkerClusterer } from '@googlemaps/markerclusterer'

//...

@ViewChild('googleMap', { static: true }) googleMap: GoogleMap
markerCluster?: MarkerClusterer

// ...

initClusterer(e) {
    console.log('initClusterer', e)
    if (!this.googleMap?.googleMap || this.markerCluster) return

    console.log(this.googleMap, this.googleMap.googleMap)
    this.markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({
      map: this.googleMap.googleMap,
      markers: this.markerElem,
    })
}
```

I did download the following dependencies
`npm i @googlemaps/markerclusterer`
`npm i @types/google.maps --save-dev`

and not the markerclustererplus, because it is deprecated.

But I get the following error.

```
vendor.js:91237 ERROR Error: MarkerClusterer class not found, cannot construct a marker cluster. Please install the MarkerClustererPlus library: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus
    at MapMarkerClusterer.ngOnInit (vendor.js:125746:15)
```

What did I did wrong ?

#### Environment

Angular: 13.2.3
CDK/Material: 13.2.3
@angukar/google-maps: 13.2.3
@types/google.maps: 3.47.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@angular/google-maps` do have a bug and did import the incorrect [library](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24478).

The workaround is to add the following script in the head of your `index.html` file. (or as script in the `angular.json` file)

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js" async defer></script>`

### Still not working?

You're surely loading the `google-map` object before you get the google map javascript ready.

To fix this issue.

1. `npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader` [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader)
2. Add this piece of code *I did it in a service and subscribed to an observable, but you just show the component once this is loaded. Up to you*

```js
google?: any // Type somehow not working that great
onMapApiDidLoad$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null)
    
this.mapLoader
  .load()
  .then((google) => {
    this.google = google

    this.onMapApiDidLoad$.next(google)
  })
  .catch(() => {
    this.onMapApiDidLoad$.next(false)
  })
```

Comment: I'm using `Angular 14.2` and `@angular/google-maps 14.2` and this does not work - it solved this error in the console: `MarkerClusterer class not found, cannot construct a marker cluster` but still shows nothing on the map.

Comment: Hi there, I'm using `Angular 14.2.12` with `@angular/google-maps 14.2.7` and this is currently  working. But I'm pretty sure you have an other problem. I've updated my answer ;)

Comment: Update: now it works, `map-marker` and `map-marker-clusterer` must be in the same html file in the same component (I used an *ngFor and separated them and that's why it didn't work) :)